# Fine-grained control over font size in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

Are there any other means of configuration for the font size (and/or dpi) and Clear Type font rendering settings in Windows 7, than represented in the control panel? (Registry hacks etc. are acceptable.)

I need to enlarge font size in the Windows 7, without making the text blurry — just as it can be done in Windows XP. I was not able to do this using control panel settings.

Comment: Which control panel settings did you try? When I use the `Set custom text size (DPI)` under the control panel "Screen" option I'm getting crisp text.

Comment: And on that same "Set Custom Text Size (DPI)" screen that leugim mentions, have you checked the box that says "Use Windows XP Style DPI Scaling"?